# Python XBBG BLP BDH Per value to biweekly

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi

I'm trying to pull historic data from Bloomberg, but I want the frequency to be biweekly. Does anyone know the constant for it?

For reference, I have 2 dataframes:

general (which I have no problem with, but this is where the start date and end date come from)

```
                      Start Date    End Date
CAN 97518704 Mtge     2021-02-15    2026-01-15
```

and new

```
new = blp.bdh(
    tickers = ['CAN 97518704 Mtge'],
    flds = ['AMT_OUTSTANDING', 'MTG_PRINC_DIST', 'MTG_FACTOR'],
    start_date = general.at['CAN 97518704 Mtge', 'Start Date'],
    end_date = general.at['CAN 97518704 Mtge', 'End Date'],
    Per = 'W',
)

    CAN 97518704 Mtge
                AMT_OUTSTANDING MTG_PRINC_DIST  MTG_FACTOR
2021-02-19  9.973236e+08    3763233.45  0.996241
2021-02-26  9.973236e+08    3763233.45  0.996241
2021-03-05  9.973236e+08    3763233.45  0.996241
2021-03-12  9.973236e+08    3763233.45  0.996241
2021-03-19  9.925217e+08    4801890.70  0.991444
... ... ... ...
2025-12-12  8.221309e+08    7138897.49  0.821238
2025-12-19  8.221309e+08    7138897.49  0.821238
2025-12-26  8.221309e+08    7138897.49  0.821238
2026-01-02  8.221309e+08    7138897.49  0.821238
2026-01-09  8.221309e+08    7138897.49  0.821238
256 rows × 3 columns
```

Is there a Per value that will return biweekly data?

Comment: Just get weekly data and take every other row?

Answer (score 2):

One workaround for the lack of a bi-weekly frequency option is to get daily data (5 days / week) and slice the DataFrame into however many weekdays you want.

```
from xbbg import blp
from datetime import datetime
    
tkr = 'CAN 97518704 Mtge'
dtStart = datetime(2021,2,15).date()
dtEnd = datetime(2026,1,15).date()

flds = ['AMT_OUTSTANDING','MTG_PRINC_DIST','MTG_FACTOR']

nWeekdays = 10
df = blp.bdh(tkr,flds,dtStart,dtEnd,Calendar='5D')[::-nWeekdays][::-1]

print(df)
```

which yields:

```
    CAN 97518704 Mtge
AMT_OUTSTANDING MTG_PRINC_DIST  MTG_FACTOR
2021-02-18  9.973236e+08    3763233.45  0.996241
2021-03-04  9.973236e+08    3763233.45  0.996241
2021-03-18  9.925217e+08    4801890.70  0.991444
2021-04-01  9.925217e+08    4801890.70  0.991444
2021-04-15  9.865371e+08    5984639.89  0.985466
... ... ... ...
2025-11-20  8.221309e+08    7138897.49  0.821238
2025-12-04  8.221309e+08    7138897.49  0.821238
2025-12-18  8.221309e+08    7138897.49  0.821238
2026-01-01  8.221309e+08    7138897.49  0.821238
2026-01-15  8.221309e+08    7138897.49  0.821238
129 rows × 3 columns
```

The `[::-nWeekdays][::-1]` construction ensures that the last date is always the end date. If instead you always want to have the start date, just use `[::nWeekdays]`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The valid values are detailed in the "Reference Services & Schemas Guide", that you can find in WAPI <Go> >> API Developers Guide.

> **Period Selection**: Determines the frequency of the output. To be used in conjunction with Period Adjustment.

```
Element              Element Value Type   Description
periodicitySelection DAILY         string Returns one data point per day.
                     WEEKLY        string Returns one data point per week.
                     MONTHLY       string Returns one data point per month.
                     QUARTERLY     string Returns one data point per quarter.
                     SEMI_ANNUALLY string Returns one data point per half year.
                     YEARLY        string Returns one data point per year.
```

> Example Syntax: `request.Set("periodicitySelection", "DAILY");`

Each value can be abbreviated using its initial.